High voltage and lightning protection
I am developing an IoT device intended for use in agricultural fields. This device features an 8-channel 220V/3V3 (opto-isolated) system and includes an energy analyzer. Additionally, it incorporates an SMPS power supply.
However, I am facing an issue where the normally 220V (phase-neutral) power supply is highly unstable and can rise up to 270V. This instability can damage the components connected to the 220V line. Furthermore, there is a significant risk of lightning strikes in the field, which has already resulted in the failure of several devices.
My questions are as follows:
What kind of protection should I implement to safeguard my components (such as IoT systems and processors) from high voltage spikes?
How can I protect my circuits from lightning strikes?
Thank you.
